# Swift can't edit UITextView and cant add text

Tags: swift

I am trying to add a UITextView to my view. I have this class:

```
import UIKit

class TextAnnotation: UITextView {

    var lastLocation:CGPoint?
    var panRecognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer?

    override init(frame: CGRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer?) {
        super.init(frame: frame, textContainer: textContainer)
        self.panRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target:self, action: #selector(StampAnnotation.detectPan))
        self.gestureRecognizers = [panRecognizer!]
        self.text = "Text Field"
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.brownColor()
        self.userInteractionEnabled = true
        self.editable = true
        self.frame = CGRect(x: frame.origin.x, y: frame.origin.y, width: 200, height: 50)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func detectPan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        let translation  = recognizer.translationInView(self.superview!)
        self.center = CGPointMake(lastLocation!.x + translation.x, lastLocation!.y + translation.y)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        // Promote the touched view
        self.superview?.bringSubviewToFront(self)

        // Remember original location
        lastLocation = self.center

    }

}
```

The background color will change to brown, but the text does not get added and when I tap on the UITextView nothing happens when I set to editable, what am I doing wrong?

Here is how I am calling this class:

```
let textCenter = touches.first!.locationInView(view)
            let textView = TextAnnotation(frame: CGRect(x: textCenter.x, y: textCenter.y, width: 200, height: 50), textContainer: NSTextContainer())

            view.addSubview(textView)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are the one who has wantonly stripped off the real gesture recognizers of this text view and replaced them with something else, effectively crippling the text view. Don't do that. Don't mess with the gesture recognizers of a text view! If interaction is enabled and editable is `true`, this text view needs to be able to do its own work.

Comment: If I remove the gestures, yes I am able to edit the text, but I still cant see the  default text or the text I am writing

Comment: Why can't I see my text?